# Why is python list showing slicing abnormality?

Tags: python, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to partition the list element recursively (like in divide and conquer) and consequently printing the sliced elements but suddenly sees unexpected abnormality(at line 6 and onwards in Output).

```
def Mergesort(a, l, r):
    if(l<r):
      mid = (r+l+1) // 2
      print(a)
      Mergesort(a[l : mid], l, mid-1)
      Mergesort(a[mid : r+1], mid, r)

a = [8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5] 
Mergesort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
```

Output:

```
[8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]
[8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1]
[8, 3, -2]
[3, -2]
[6, 7, 4, 1]
[1]
[]
[2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: What exactly was your expected output?

Comment: [8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]
[8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1]
[8, 3, -2]
[3, -2]
[6, 7, 4, 1]
[6, 7]
[4, 1]
[2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]
[2, -1, 0]
[-1, 0]
[9, 12, 11, 5]
[9, 12]
[11, 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  Actually, while passing sliced list in function, index start from zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `l, r` in `def Mergesort` is not precise. When you Mergesort your RHS array`a=[2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]`, it is actually running: `Mergesort([2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5],7,10)`, but not `Mergesort([2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5],0,3)`. Since len(a)=7, it will only return an empty array`[]`.
I modified the codes:

```
def Mergesort(a, l, r):
    if(l<r):
        mid = (r+l+1) // 2
        print (a)
   #    
        Mergesort(a[l : mid], 0, len(a)-1)
        Mergesort(a[mid : r+1],0, len(a)-1)

a = [8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5] 
Mergesort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
```

Now it can split both right and left arrays. Output if you `print (a)` within `if` clause:

```
[8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]
[8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1]
[8, 3, -2, 6, 7, 4, 1]
[8, 3, -2]
[8, 3, -2]
[8]
[3, -2]
[3]
[-2]
[]
[6, 7, 4, 1]
[6, 7, 4]
[6, 7]
[6]
[7]
[4]
[1]
[]
[2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]
[2, -1, 0, 9, 12, 11, 5]
[2, -1, 0]
[2, -1, 0]
[2]
[-1, 0]
[-1]
[0]
[]
[9, 12, 11, 5]
[9, 12, 11]
[9, 12]
[9]
[12]
[11]
[5]
[]
```

Notice that is code is still not perfect and needs work (but it solves the splitting issue that you raised), I would suggest improvements in

1) definition of `mid` so it correctly split even-number array;

2) definition of `l` and `r` so that it would not split single-element array.